# How localstorage data append in formData

Tags: javascript, php, json, local-storage, codeigniter-4

I append my localstorage data in formData

```
let products = [];    
for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)
     {
      x = localStorage.key(i);
      if (x !='debugbar-time-new' && x !='debugbar-time')
      {
        item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(x))
        products.push({'_id' : item['_id'] , 'title':item['title'], 'quantity':item['quantity']});
      }
    }
    formData.append('products',JSON.stringify(products))
```

now my data in this form

```
products, [{"_id":5,"title":"bicycle","quantity":1},{"_id":2,"title":"i7","quantity":3},{"_id":4,"title":"i5","quantity":1},{"_id":1,"title":"i5","quantity":37},{"_id":3,"title":"i7","quantity":1}]
```

I get data in my controller

```
$req = $this->request->getVar('products');
```

I receive data in encoded form.
How do I convert it in array and other forms?

Comment: Isn't it `json_decode($this->request->getVar('products'))` ?

Comment: i tried it but not working

Comment: ** Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string **
this error show

Comment: json_decode($this->request->getVar('products') , true);

it's working

Comment: var products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));

Answer (score 0):

just decode your encoded data with true parameter

```
json_decode($this->request->getVar('products') , true);
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.